# Python SFTP Connection Fabric files.exist does not find the file

Tags: python-3.x, sftp, fabric

I'm maintaining code written by a retired colleague. This code uses `Fabric` 2.7.1 to download files from our old FTP server.

```
from fabric import Connection
from patchwork import files
...
if not files.exists(conn, groups['file']):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f'No such file: {groups["file"]}')
...
```

This code worked for many years with our **old FTP server**. We must use SFTP now and the new server no longer allows `ssh` from internal IPs. I guess the above code used in fact `ssh` and not `ftp` as my retired colleague stated.

With the **new** **server**, It always runs into the `FileNotFoundError`, the file and path are fully correct and checked a dozen times. I can see the file on my sftp shell.

I wonder, why a third party library should allow an `Fabric` object to be handed over? `files.exists` seems to be a standard python library, not specialized for SFTP. 'I don't fully understand how this could work for years.

I also found [this snippet](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/getting-started.html?highlight=failed#bringing-it-all-together)

```
 if c.run('test -f /opt/mydata/myfile', warn=True).failed:
```

but this leads to "This service allows sftp connections only."

So, how do I properly check if a files exists with `fabric` 2.7.1? The docs says there is only a `put` and a `get` method. I'm unable to upgrade Fabric as this breaks dependencies. There are so many code parts like this that I need a simple-as-possible approach to get it working again.

Comment: `files.exists` is not standard Python library. It's a third party library, that obviously can work with 3rd party "contexts". + Fabric indeed supports SSH/SFTP only, not FTP. So this part (both its sentences) makes no sense to me: *"This code worked for many years with our old FTP server. We must use SFTP now and the new server no longer allows ssh from internal IPs."*.

Comment: The old FTP server allowed SSH from internal IPs, so I guess the whole code used indeed SSH and not FTP as the old developer told me. The new server does no longer offer SSH but it allows SFTP and `fabric` should be able to deal with SFTP, too.

Comment: While I do not know `patchwork`, I cannot imagine that the `files.exists` could use "SSH" (= shell commands). I'm quite sure it always used SFTP (you keep using "FTP" although it seems that "FTP" was never involved in your project).

Comment: My admin colleague says, that the old server did not speak SFTP. Just FTP and SSH. But even if that's true, why isn't f`files.exist`working then? The file exists in the given path. I can download the file with get when I comment out the exception. Could `chroot` matter? That's also new on the new server.

Comment: `files.exists` relies on SSH commands, see files.py line 30. It just executes test -e filename, which is not available in pure sftp.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for this behavior:

`files.exist` relies on `ssh` method `test` ([GitHub](https://github.com/fabric/patchwork/blob/master/patchwork/files.py#L46))

This method is just not available on pure SFTP servers. OpenSSH does not allow to configure methods available via SFTP.

Due to `chroot` it's also difficult to allow SSH access from given list of IPs.

I will never use any code from `Fabric`. Don't know how I can get my code working, yet. Paramiko itself might be better but it's much work to migrate code to another framework.

Comment: Interesting +1 – But then your question never had anything to do with SFTP in the first place (let only FTP).